# Create an array of key difference using two array

Tags: php, arrays

How can we find key deference array using two arrays like
First Array :

```
$array_1 = array('300','200','500');
```

Second Array :

```
$array_2 = array('500','300','200');
```

`$array_2` is generating by applying `rsort` to `$array_1`

Then i want to generate an array of key by comparing value of `$array_1` and key of `$array_2`.Output will be an array of

```
$key_array = ('1','2','0');
```

Comment: Just to make it easier, the op seems to want to find out where the values are now (to what index the values go after sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_flip()` on `$array_2` to convert the keys to values and vice versa. Then you can easily find the original keys.

```
$flip_2 = array_flip($array_2);
$key_array = array_map(function($el) use ($flip_2) { return $flip_2[$el]; }, $array_1);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/UkRyJ5)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$array_1 = array('300','200','500');
$array_2 = array('500','300','200');
$key_array = array();
foreach($array_1 as $arr1) {
   $key_array[] = array_search($arr1, $array_2); // get key in array_2 for value of array1
}
print_r($key_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 0
)
```